# Matrix returned always contains 1's

Tags: c#, .net, matrix

I am writing a program to create a matrix that will be filled with 1's and 0's.

```
var matrix = new int[3,3];

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        int rand = random.Next(0,2);
        matrix[i, j] = rand;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[i, j] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The program always returns a matrix filled with 1's. I want it to be random i-e that contains 1's and 0's. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move this line of code

```
var random = new Random();
```

before this line of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
```

That will solve your problem. Please have a look [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uQq7kt).

> Why this happens?

As it is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number),

> Every time you do new Random() it is initialized using the clock. This
>   means that in a tight loop you get the same value lots of times. You
>   should keep a single Random instance and keep using Next on the same
>   instance.